# Disable-ComputerRestore doesn't turn off system protection

Tags: windows, windows-7, powershell, wmi

I'm programmatically trying to enable/disable System Restore in Windows 7. I have enable system restore working "Enable-ComputerRestore", but disable is giving me issues.

```
Disable-ComputerRestore -drive "C:\"
```

doesn't set my C: drive to "Turn off system protection". It sets it to "Only restore previous versions of files" instead. Anyone have a clue as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solving this using WMI and the following C# code adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8101233/831803).

```
    public void disableSystemRestore(string drive)
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\localhost\\root\\default");
            ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("SystemRestore");
            ObjectGetOptions options = new ObjectGetOptions();
            ManagementClass process = new ManagementClass(scope, path, options);
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = process.GetMethodParameters("Disable");
            inParams["Drive"] =  drive;
            ManagementBaseObject outParams = process.InvokeMethod("Disable", inParams, null);
        }
        catch(ManagementException err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while trying to execute the WMI method: " + err.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do it localy (no remote) as administrator :

[image]

The command

[image]

Be careful, you have to close the system properties windo and reopen it to see the result.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am doing it locally, and as Administrator.

Here is a before screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/UmrpY.png).

Here is a after screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/pV9j4.png).

Comment: I reproduce your trouble by manualy choosing one time "only restore previous version of files" !

Comment: Is this some sort of bug? I'm so confused as to what to do. I'm trying out a few things using C# and WMI, but I'm not having any luck.